# How to cancel the term "sotto voce"

Tags: terminology, dynamics

I have always understood the term *sotto voce* to be more of an expressive instruction - a feeling - than a specific dynamic mark.  It's used to mark a passage (often in vocal music, but it's not limited to vocal music) that should be performed very quietly.  But it doesn't seem to take the place of a proper dynamic mark.

In this Brahms piece, for instance, it is paired with *p* to tell the performer not only to play at a soft dynamic, but *also* to play in an understated manner; with restraint.

**Brahms Symphony 3**

[image: Brahms excerpt]

Now here is the question:  Assuming that a regular dynamic marking is also required, how does one "cancel" the sotto voce instruction?  Is there an opposite term like arco/pizz. that is expected?  Does the instruction disappear with the next dynamic marking to appear?  **How should one cancel the indication of sotto voce?**

If the context is important, the passage is soprano/alto in a choral piece, and the dynamic is indeed piano.

As a possible answer, a further search brought me to this bassoon moment in the same piece.  Is *mezza voce* (translated from Italian: half/medium voice) perhaps Brahms' answer?  EDIT: Aaron beat me to it!

[image]

Comment: Note, btw, the _f_ at rehearsal B. We can probably presume that there's no "forte sotto voce." I guess it's a fair question, how does "_p e sotto voce_" compare to "_pp_", e.g. after reh. A? For what it's worth, I think Brahms threw it in at the beginning and not thereafter because, as you say, it's an expressive instruction, and once the movement "gets going" the bassist presumably knows when to be subdued.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three "voce"s for music:

- *sotto voce*: hushed voice (lit. "under the voice")
- *mezza voce*: half voice
- *piena voce*: full voice

Comment: Would a dynamic mark, especially at mp or above, cancel it out also?

Comment: @ToddWilcox Anything mp or lower, I would have to give it real interpretive thought; but, mf or higher I would interpret as a cancellation. I'm not aware of any convention.